# Override toString method for a single object

Tags: groovy, overriding, tostring

Suppose I have this code:

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass()
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass()
```

The `toString()` method in `MyClass.groovy` is implemented like this:

```
String toString() {
    "Instance of MyClass"
}
```

However, I would like `obj1` to return something else when printed. How would I do that? I tried these two options, but neither worked.

```
obj1.metaClass.toString = {
    "Object 1"
}
```

and

```
obj1.toString = {
    "Object 1"
}
```

The first simply didn't work and the second caused an error. What is the correct way to do this in Groovy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
obj1.metaClass.toString = { ->
    "Object 1"
}
```

By not including `->` the closure took a default parameter, but since the actual `toString()` method does not take any parameters, I was overriding the wrong method.

***Edit***: This only works if you manually include the call to `toString()` as in: `print obj1.toString()`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/50c3498ab5e4609ba5dadb1537a25f29

Comment: @JeffScottBrown It only works if you manually include the call to `toString()`.

Comment: That gist I linked invokes `sb.toString()`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/e12cb0ccac705560ef344c6e0b31b59c